# Azure storage. Got 403 [url] (CORS not enabled or no matching rule found for this request.)

Tags: azure, web, cors, azure-blob-storage, preflight

I am developing some web-page that allows to upload files from client side to my azure storage directly. 
My files are stored on Azure BLOB Storage in Portal.
For this I am using 'azure-storage' v2.8.1 package from npm.

While I am trying to create container:

```
    const blobService = AzureStorage.createBlobServiceWithSas(storageUri, sasToken)
    blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(containerName, { publicAccessLevel: 'blob' }, (error, result, response) => {.....})
```

I got errors:

1. OPTIONS [url to my storage] 403 (CORS not enabled or no matching rule found for this request.)
2. Failed to load [url to my storage]: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am sure that blob connection string is correct - I checked it. 
In addition I know that I can edit CORS for my storage on azure.portal.
Currently it is empty.

Should I need to add/edit there some CORS?
Do someone know solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should I need to add/edit there some CORS? Do someone know solution?

Yes, you need to add the CORS setting for storage blob service. By default, CORS is disabled for each service. We could get more information about CORS from this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing--CORS--Support-for-the-Azure-Storage-Services?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

> **Note**: CORS is not supported for Premium Storage accounts.

We also could set it from Azure portal. More details please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I just added all configuration for CORS. And it worked for first few times.
But know I started to receive another error: 
`HEAD [url] 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)`

Comment: @AlexandrMendelevych, for how long your sas token is valid ? maybe you should just generate a new sas token

Comment: @Thomas that all. Everything working. The issue was on my local machine. Timezone was wrong therefore I was unable to pass authentication.

Comment: What timezone should be used on the local machine?